# MvxFrameLayout derived class doesn't draw child

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I created a test MvxFrameLayout derived class, which I want to draw a child at 0,0 with size 24x24:

```
    public class MyCustomLayout : MvxFrameLayout
    {
        public MyCustomLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
        }

        public MyCustomLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, IMvxAdapterWithChangedEvent adapter) : base(context, attrs)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            if (!changed)
            {
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < this.ChildCount; ++i)
            {
                var child = this.GetChildAt(i);
                child.Layout(0, 0, 24, 24);
            }
        }
    }
```

Which is used in an activity layout (FirstView.axml) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <hotspotappandroid.droid.views.MyCustomLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Hotspots"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/hotspot" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The view model which has one item:

```
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public string[] Hotspots { get; private set; }

    public FirstViewModel()
    {
        this.Hotspots = new string[] { "A" };
    }
}
```

The hotspot.xml is an ImageView with an image (circle.png) of 24x24:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/circle" />
```

The problem is the circle image is not being drawn.

If in hotspot.xml I change `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_height="fill_parent` to `wrap_content`, the image is drawn, but not correctly.
The image is drawn in half. It looks like the image is drawn scaled to double of its size and it's cropped by half (probably due to `child.Layout(0, 0, 24, 24)).

I am not sure what is going on. I see that the `child` in `OnLayout` is of type `cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.droid.views.MvxListItemView` instead of 'ImageView' because that I would have expected. Maybe that has something to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MvxFrameLayout` works by inflating a child `MvxListItemView` for each child. The `MvxListItemView` itself inherits from `FrameLayout` and has default layout parameters.

According to the docs - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html - this means each child FrameLayout should be sized:

> The size of the FrameLayout is the size of its largest child (plus padding), visible or not (if the FrameLayout's parent permits)

Since you are specifying `fill_parent` for the `ImageView` inner grandchildren here, then I guess that is what is causing your inner views to be zero-sized.

In order to give your child frames some size, it might be better to give them `ImageView` sizes directly in the inner child XML, instead of requesting `fill_parent`

---

If you do want to return an `ImageView` directly and to use that as the Child - without the intermediate `MvxListItemView` then in the latest MvvmCross source I believe you can:

- inherit a class `MyImageView` from `ImageView` and add an `IMvxListItemView` implementation
- use a custom Adapter which creates and returns `MyImageView` in an overridden `CreateBindableView` - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxAdapter.cs#L287

Comment: I specified a width and height for the Image and it still doesn't work . I will mark your comment as answer though :) I am not sure how to do the Adapter work and I am in hurry. I will do a quick&dirty custom view